# Error with cardView in android: 'Failed to find style with id 0x7fff0062 in current theme

Tags: android, themes, android-cardview

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#009688"
tools:context="com.echodevteam.isaac.echo_simplyawesome.Login"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Echo"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:id="@+id/echoText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Simply Awesome"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:id="@+id/simplyText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/echoText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewLogin"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="18dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/simplyText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Welcome back!"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textColor="#009688"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/ETuname"
            android:textColorHint="#E0E0E0"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/ETpass"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColorHint="#E0E0E0"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ETuname"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ETuname"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ETuname" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/showBox"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ETpass"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Blogin"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Blogin" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:background="#009688"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/Blogin"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ETpass"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ETpass"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ETpass" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="Forgot password? Tap here."
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/forgotText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Blogin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:background="#009688"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/Bregister"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/forgotText"
            android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Blogin"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Blogin" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.echodevteam.isaac.echo_simplyawesome">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UserInterfeOne"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_user_interfe_one"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I would appreciate it if someone will help me fix this code with the card view. 
I have it in my gradle as compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'.
I am getting the error "Failed to find style with id 0x7fff0062 in current theme"

Comment: change your compiled sdk version in build.gradle and try

Answer (score 2):

You need to use AppCompat theme to use a CardView:   `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` 
in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Hey sir thank you for your response. I just refreshed my XML file and it went back to normal. Thank you tho.

Comment: Hey, This may be a little bit late but you should mark this answer as the correct .
It could save the users a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Try to rebuild your project, Build --> Rebuild Project.